# JQuery's .load function won't pass variable to my PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm aware that this is possible using JQuery's ajax functions but I'm specifically wanting to try do this using JQuery's `.load()` function.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv-file">
    <p class="upload-button">Upload</p>
    <p class="upload-output"></p>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.upload-button').click(function() {
    var formData = $('.form').serializeArray();
    $('.upload-output').load('upload.php', formData);
});
```

When I click on the `upload-button` the form is serialized and sent to my PHP file called `upload.php`. This is the contents of `upload.php` - I'm currently just checking to see if it recieves the file at all:

```
if(isset($_FILES['csv-file'])){
    echo 'found file';
} else echo 'no file';
```

All of this looks fine but for some reason it returns `no file` every time and I'm not sure why.

I've tried different input types like a `text` field, `textarea` and they all work but whenever I try to pass an input with type `file` it doesn't work. Why is this? and how can I get the file through to my PHP file using `.load()`? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is `upload.php` in the same folder as this file?

Comment: yes it is and I know my html is finding it because it does everything else in the 'upload.php' file apart from upload the file I have tried to pass through

Comment: Well you need to wrap a function around `$('.form').serializeArray()`, right now it looks like you are trying to pass it as a parameter.  After `upload.php,` add `function(){}` and move `$('.form').serializeArray()` inside that function.

Comment: @AaronEveleth that still doesn't work....

Comment: Well first, your PHP file isn't passing any data back. You need to `echo json_encode(<your_data_here>);` You also need to add the `response` parameter(1st of 3) to the callback function I had you add.

Comment: Actually you may not need `response`. I'm not very experienced with the `.load` function. Just reviewing the documentation. By the way, you said "without using ajax". I just want to clarify this is still ajax, it's just a shorthand method. You may have an easier time with the normal `$.ajax` function which allows you to still run your code, but also neatly pass any data to the DOM in a success function.

Comment: @AaronEveleth thanks for your help here. Could you write an official answer with how you think the php and javascript should look? That may help here :)

Comment: Before I create the answer, I need to know what data you intend to pass. Can you add that to your php file in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't upload files with Ajax that way because .serialize() only gives you the file names.

Use FormData:

```
$('.upload-button').click(function() {
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$('.upload-output').load('upload.php', formData); });
```

Also see: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

And: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously?rq=1)